# How to change the Name of the Widget?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, widgets

In magento **CMS->managepages->Homepage->**in Content i have added a WIDGET called New Products.
I want to change the Name of the Widget. IS there any way to change the name of the Widget.

Comment: This is not clear.. Please make it clear..thanks..

Comment: In Homepage content i have added a widget called new products. so the widget appear in the homepage by the name of "newproducts". i want to change the name "newproducts". is there any way to change

Comment: Do you mean there is some text shown on the front end you want to change or simply the name shown in the admin section?

Comment: i want to change the name in frontend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `yourtheme/template/catalog/product/new.phtml` and change the name.